# delay is not working in assembly 8086

Tags: assembly, delay, x86-16

I'm trying to develop tetris, and I have some issues with the delay.

I'm using this as a delay:

```
    mov ah, 86h
    mov cx, 0Fh
    mov dx, 4240h
    int 15h
```

But as you can see in [this](https://gyazo.com/ce498868d60bfeed7afadf2256d64cc9) GIF, when I try to move the block it's going crazy all over the place

I really need help with the delay as fast as possible.

To download the full code files press [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8lkm7wcygh1a3zd/AACAU2Ce_axfioRj7AVHdGAqa?dl=0).

Comment: Verify `CF` is clear after return. Verify that it is indeed the delay that's causing problems, such as by using a delay loop.

Comment: DOSBox is known to have difficulties with this delay function. Take a look at [this](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/101035/a-low-tech-approach-to-measuring-game-speed)

Comment: I tried the loop delay but it's not working either. 
The problem can be in the drawing procedure?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> G_Init:
>  call Gravity
>  mov ah, 1h
>  int 16h
>  jz chk_Key
>  jmp G_Init
> chk_Key:
> ```

The erratic behaviour of your program comes from the fact that you're not correctly interpreting the outcome from checking the keyboard with BIOS function 01h at `int 16h`. When the ZF is set it means that there is **no key available** and so you should jump back to *G_Init*. If the ZF is clear just fall through in the *chk_Key* part, but remember **to actually remove the key** from the keyboard buffer.

```
G_Init:
 call Gravity
 mov  ah, 01h     ;Test for key
 int  16h
 jz   G_Init      ;No key available!
 mov  ah, 00h     ;Remove key
 int  16h
chk_Key:
```

---

Many people have trouble with `jz`/`jnz` because it's counterintuitive:

`jz` reads as "jump if **zero**" but acts based on ZF=**1**
`jnz` reads as "jump if **non-zero**" but acts based on ZF=**0**

---

A second problem I've found is that at the labels *R_Left* and *R_Right* you are using `lea bx,[location]` where in fact you should be using `mov bx,[location]`. You don't need the address **of** the *location* variable itself, but you do need the address stored **in** the *location* variable.

```
R_Left:
 call clblk
 mov  bx, [location]    ;Makes BX point within 'pic.inc'
 sub  [spx], 5
 call Draw2d
 jmp  delay
R_Right:
 call clblk
 mov  bx, [location]
```